# Futter/dart: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 getActivitiesResponseModel!.activities!
        .where((element) => element.status == "Pending")
        .first
```

when there is not found any item related to above faltering than throw **bad state exception**.
I have searched but **orElse: () => nul**l callback is not defined for where function and i need only single object.so what i should do to handle this Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception raising because of .first method, that have to return single object from list.
In your case, there might be no elements by filtering, then, you should check, if your list isn't empty, like that.

```
Object? _searchitem;
var filteredList = getActivitiesResponseModel!.activities!
        .where((element) => element.status == "Pending");
    if (filteredList.isNotEmpty)
    {
    _searchitem = filteredList.first;
    }
```

Or, you can also use .firstWhere(), where you need to define orElse funct to handle errors.

```
getActivitiesResponseModel!.activities!
        .firstWhere((element) => element.status == "Pending", orElse: () => null);
```

Comment: Konstantin Gorynin tnx this is working now for me

Answer (score 0):

```
 getActivitiesResponseModel!.activities!
```

This is a very bad usage. You need to make sure this datas are not null.

```
if(getActivitiesResponseModel != null) 
 { 
   if(getActivitiesResponseModel!.activities != null){
     getActivitiesResponseModel!.activities!
        .where((element) => element.status == "Pending")
        .first
}}
```

Can you try like this?

Comment: tnx for structuring the code but getActivitiesResponseModel!.activities! have more elements but not has element which has status pending than throw Exception

Comment: can you check also is not empty

Answer (score 0):

```dart
if(getActivitiesResponseModel != null) 
 { 
   if(getActivitiesResponseModel!.activities != null){
     getActivitiesResponseModel!.activities!
        .where((element) => element.status == "Pending")
        .first
}}
```